# How to read account infrastructure inside my AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to read what are the services in my account and how they are linked. I have a VPC which spans across different subnets. Subnets has different resources like EC2, RDS etc. We have route table configured that shows incoming and outgoing connections. By reading this route table I can identify if my EC2 is accessing any resource in other subnet. Is there a way I can get some kind of metadata structure of my whole AWS account using python SDK which can show me connections between different services across network.

Comment: technically yes. practically: this is difficult if you want to cover all services. Particularly the VPC config can span 10s of service with 1000s of resources, cross-acount, cross-region, etc. Other interactions cannot be determined looking at the resources alone, e.g. wether a lambda writes to a given s3 bucket or a dynamodb table, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try out AWS Config and see if it meets your need.

> AWS Config provides a detailed view of the configuration of AWS resources in your AWS account. This includes how the resources are related to one another and how they were configured in the past so that you can see how the configurations and relationships change over time.